# Can't use images from k8s.gcr.io registry in my kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry

I've setup a k8s cluster on a bare metal ubuntu machine using RKE.
There is no problem creating deployments with images from docker.io.

But I can't create deployments which are based on gcr.io:

```
Warning  Failed     10s   kubelet            Failed to pull image "k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/kube-webhook-certgen:v1.0@sha256:f3b6b39a6062328c095337b4cadcefd1612348fdd5190b1dcbcb9b9e90bd8068": rpc er │
ror: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get "https://k8s.gcr.io/v2/": dial tcp: lookup k8s.gcr.io: Temporary failure in name resolution                                                   │
Warning  Failed     10s   kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

Why is k8s.gcr.io blocked and where can I enable it?

Comment: Check your DNS server. "lookup k8s.gcr.io: Temporary failure in name resolution"

Comment: @BMitch How do I check it?

Answer (score 1):

[According to Rancher](https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v1.6/en/environments/registries/#using-google-container-registry)

"If you want to use Google Container Registry, you will have to use a service account JSON key file. Don’t forget to grant the correct permissions to the Google Cloud Storage bucket containing your Container Registry images.

Specify the registry address according to the region your images are stored. Use _json_key as username and use the full contents of the service account JSON key file as password."